# how do we calculate the number of reads/misses of the cache in this code snippet?

Tags: caching, computer-science, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I'm trying to get an understanding of how to calculate the errors in the code, from the link on this page, [Example given from text book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68325400/how-do-we-calculate-the-number-of-reads-misses-of-the-cache-in-this-code-snippet). I can see where the calculations come from, but as the values are the same (32), I cannot work out how to do the calculation should the value in the two loops differ. Using different sized loops, what would the calculations be please?

`

```
for (i = 32; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (j = 128; j >= 0; j--) {
        total_x += grid[i][j].x;
    }
}

for (i = 128; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (j = 32; j >= 0; j--) {
         total_y += grid[i][j].y;
    }
}
```

`
If we had a matrix with 128 rows and 24 columns (instead of the 32 x 32 in the example), using 32-bit integers, and with each memory block able to hold 16 bytes, how do we calculate the number of compulsory misses on the top loop?

Also, if we use a direct-mapped cache holding 256 bytes of data, how would we calculate the number of all the data cache misses when running the top loop?

Finally, if we flip it and use the bottom loop, how does the maths change (if it does) for the points above?

Apologies as this is all new to me and I just want to understand the maths behind it so I can answer the problem, rather than just be given an answer.

Nothing - it's a theoretical question

Comment: Are the 2D array dimensions always the same as the loop bounds, so you're not leaving any elements untouched?  When you say "flip it", do you mean running the second loop first, or do you just mean looking at the 2nd loop after the 1st loop has primed the cache, not changing/flipping anything in the code?  You haven't specified how the array is aligned, whether any of the `struct { int x,y; };` elements can be split across cache lines, e.g. if the first element's `x` started at an odd multiple of 4.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes - sorry I should've explained in the first instance, just running the top loop, and the in the second instance running the second loop (the flip).

Yes, the 2D array dimensions match the loop bounds, and the array starts at 0, with a machine word being 4 bytes, and each memory block holds 16 bytes. The memory is byte accessible.

Apologies for the sketchy information, I'm struggling to understand what is relevant and what isn't in doing the calculations.

Comment: You can and should [edit] your question with those details.